# android : get the url from imageview?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm using `picasso` to load image from a server to an `ImageView`. I would like to know if it's possible to **extract that URL** from the **imageview** itself.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can take advantage of the method `View#setTag(String)`. and `View#getTag()` . You can store the url by calling the `View#setTag(String)` method, and use the `View#getTag()` method to retrieve the url. :)

Comment: @AxeFox: Depending on where and how the `ImageView` is used, this may not be reliable. In particular, in recycling scenarios, Picasso can automatically detect and manage `ImageView` widgets that get recycled as part of `ListView`, `RecyclerView`, etc. scrolling, and the tag may get out of sync with the actual URL that Picasso loads in there, depending upon what the user does.

Comment: @CommonsWare I didn't knw dat, thanks for the lesson. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the `ImageView` does not know the URL. An `ImageView` can get its image from any number of `Drawable` implementations. Picasso will wind up creating a `BitmapDrawable`, and by that time, the URL is long gone, replaced by the `Bitmap`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will figure out another solution for my problem